# Convergence of a subsequence of convergent sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(t_n)$ be a nondecreasing sequence of positive numbers tending to $\infty$ such that $$t_{n+1}\leq t_n+1,\ \ t_1=0\ \ \ \text{and also}  \ \ \ n>t_n.$$

I wonder but can not find if the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to a finite limit $L$ then $(x_{t_n})$ converges to the same limit?

Comment: If a sequence converges then every subsequence converges to the same limit. The question is whether your $(x_{t_n})$ makes sense (i.e. whether $t_n$ is a natural number and $t_n$ is unbounded, so whether it actually is a subsequence).

Comment: note that -- even if the $t_n$ are integers your conditions would allow that, e.g., $t_n=1$ for all $n$. In that case you don't have a subsequence but a new (constant) sequence.

Comment: But in the case $t_n=1$ for all $n$ the sequence $x_{t_n}$ converges to $x_1$ not $L.$ This makes my mind blurry.

Comment: In that case you don't have a sequence. All you have is $x\_1$